# How can I change styles of an array element in react native

Tags: react-native

I leave a small code of sample of as I have my code, in fact my code I show it inside a FlatList... but here I leave him something similar in .map that is practically the same thing, they are dynamic Views, I wish that on having clicked in the button, that View change Styles (Position Abosulte, Width, Backgorund color and more)

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

let shopping = ['bread', 'milk', 'cheese', 'hummus', 'noodles'];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {shopping.map((data, idx) => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 70,
              backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
              marginTop: 5,
              marginBottom: 5,
              borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
              borderWidth: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text>Tex: {data}</Text>

//I press this buttom, i want change this View Styles!!!, only this view

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
              <View
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: 30,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
                  marginTop: 5,
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderRadius: 15,
                }}>
                <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>Change</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a state variable and then set it to change the style.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({changeStyleIndex:index})}>
          <View
            style={this.state.changeStyleIndex != index{
              width: '100%',
              height: 30,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
              marginTop: 5,
              marginBottom: 5,
              borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 15,
            }:{change style goes here}}>
            <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>Change</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: thanks friend, another question, if I want that particular View is transformed into a modal? example, position abosulte, dimensions to 100%? is to apply a FullScreen to a video, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

let shopping = ['bread', 'milk', 'cheese', 'hummus', 'noodles'];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      BackColor = '#f7f7f7',
      StateWidth: '100%'
    }
  }

  HandleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      BackColor: 'red',
      StateWidth: '50%'
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { BackColor, StateWidth } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {shopping.map((data, idx) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                width: { StateWidth },
                height: 70,
                backgroundColor: { BackColor },
                marginTop: 5,
                marginBottom: 5,
                borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
                borderWidth: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text>Tex: {data}</Text>

              //I press this buttom, i want change this View Styles!!!, only this view

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.HandleChange }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 30,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
                    marginTop: 5,
                    marginBottom: 5,
                    borderColor: '#dfdfdf',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderRadius: 15,
                  }}>
                  <Text style={{ width: '100%' }}>Change</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
```

I used the component by class, but change it to function and it will give crt, the logic is basically this.

Comment: thanks friend, another question, if I want that particular View is transformed into a modal? example, position abosulte, dimensions to 100%? is to apply a FullScreen to a video, How can I do it?

Comment: with the react-native modal component itself